# generalized subscripting and superscripting in vim

Tags: vim

Using the text editor `vim`, one can produce subscripted and superscripted numbers by using the digraphs <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>-`ns` for subscription and <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>-`nS` for superscription, where `n` is an Arabic numeral. Is there a mechanism for generalized subscription and superscription of other characters (e.g., Latin or Greek letters)?

Comment: Do you mean control-KnS (captial 's' rather than '$')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking about the UTF-8 "[phonetic extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_Extensions)" block?  Vim doesn't have default digraphs for those characters, but you can still enter them by pressing <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd>, `[4 character hex code]`.

Additionally, you can create your own digraphs with the decimal version of the code. For example, this creates a digraph for superscript "a":

```
:digraph aS 7491
```

Just be aware that digraph "aS" already exists so you will be overriding it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Unicode phonetic extensions block. I notice that only a subset of the available subscripted and superscripted letters are available. A few more are provided by the phonetic extensions supplement block. Do you know of a chart that includes all the possible subscripted and superscripted letters? Also, my version of `vim` expects Unicode values to be entered in hexadecimal notation (to achieve superscripted "a", I needed to enter `1D43` rather than `7491`, as in your example). What dictates the expected radix of the character code?

Comment: I see that the subscripted and superscripted character set in Unicode is incomplete (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts).